# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).live is not a function

Tags: jquery, oop, codeigniter-3, pyrocms

I am using jquery 1.10.2 and I'm having **Uncaught TypeError: $(...).live is not a function**. I'm using Codeigniter for development with pyrocms. Below I have written the code:-

```
public static function close()
    {
        return '</form><script>$(document).ready(function(){$("a.close").live("click", function(e){ e.preventDefault();$(this).fadeTo(200, 0);$(this).parent().fadeTo(200, 0);$(this).parent().slideUp(400, function(){$(this).remove()})})});</script>';
    }
```

I'm new to this. Any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

**Edit:-**

From the below function I am calling the close function. please check the below code:-

```
public static function form($form_name, $output_array=false)
    {

        if ($output_array)
        {
            $return            = self::get_fields_arrays($form_name);
            $return['header']  = self::open($form_name) . $return['header'];
            $return['footer'] .= self::close();
        } else {
            $return  = self::open($form_name);
            $return .= self::get_fields($form_name);
            $return .= self::close();
        }

        self::$_ci->load->library('jquery_validation');
        if ($valid = self::get_validation_array($form_name))
        {
            self::$_ci->jquery_validation->set_rules($valid);
            if (is_array($return))
            {
                $return['footer'] .= self::$_ci->jquery_validation->run('#frm-'.$form_name);
            }
            else
            {
                $return .= self::$_ci->jquery_validation->run('#frm-'.$form_name);
            }
        }

        return $return;
    }
```

From this a tag it is getting called.

```
<li class="single current parent"><a href="http://php-pc/adina225.dev/hunter-valley-wine-club/wine-club-application">Wine Club Application</a></li>
```

Jogi Mehul please let me know if you need any more help.

I have edited the close function as Jogi suggested. So it looks like below:-

```
public static function close()
    {
        return '</form><script>$(document).ready(function(){$("a.close").on("click", function(e){ e.preventDefault();$(this).fadeTo(200, 0);$(this).parent().fadeTo(200, 0);$(this).parent().slideUp(400, function(){$(this).remove()})})});</script>';
    }
```

now I'm having the below error:- **Uncaught ReferenceError: pyroforms is not defined**

```
private function build_script($form_name) 
    {
        $script = '<script>$(document).ready(function() { pyroforms.init($("'.$form_name.'"), {submitHandler: function(form) { pyroforms.submit($("'.$form_name.'"), form)}, rules: %s,messages: %s});})</script>';
        return sprintf($script, $this->rules, ($this->messages ? $this->messages : '{}'));
    }
```

Comment: I dont know what is your requirement. Why you are writing jquery in controller instead of view?.

Comment: well, I'm using pyrocms so I have to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the following code solved my problem.

```
/**
    * Build jQuery validationcode
    *
    * @access private
    * @param  string
    * @return string
    */
    private function build_script($form_name) 
    {
        $script = '<script>$(document).ready(function() { function pyroforms(){} pyroforms.init = function(){}; new pyroforms(); pyroforms.init($("'.$form_name.'"), {submitHandler: function(form) { pyroforms.submit($("'.$form_name.'"), form)}, rules: %s,messages: %s});})</script>';
        return sprintf($script, $this->rules, ($this->messages ? $this->messages : '{}'));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The live() method was deprecated in jQuery version 1.7, and removed in version 1.9. Use the on() method instead. Please refer https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_live.asp

```
public static function close()
    {
        return '</form><script>$(document).ready(function(){$("a.close").on("click", function(e){ e.preventDefault();$(this).fadeTo(200, 0);$(this).parent().fadeTo(200, 0);$(this).parent().slideUp(400, function(){$(this).remove()})})});</script>';
    }
```

Comment: I know that I'm not able to modify this code so I wanted some help.

Comment: @AlekStephanok I have updated answer please try above snippet.

Comment: @AlekStephanok can you please let me know when you would to call this function?

Comment: I'm having **Uncaught ReferenceError: pyroforms is not defined** error after changing my snippet with yours.

Comment: @AlekStephanok can you let me know, while click on a tag, what you would like to do? So, I can help you. Can you paste your whole form? So, It will more convenient to give proper answer to you please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200879/discussion-between-jogi-mehul-and-alek-stephanok).

Comment: Check your reference where you  put `jquery`, If its not in `head` section of your page then move that on the head section, because `jQuery` is needed to load initially, and at the first load if want to write `jQuery` code in `$(document).ready( function(){})`.